# How do I restore Dolphin instead of Gwenview as default file manager

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

In the 2 years or so I have used Kubuntu 12.04, Dolphin has been my default file manager and Gwenview my default image viewer. Gwenview can also double up as a file manager, which can be useful when organising images and videos, but it provides less details (such as dates) on the files.

I have a number of icons on my desktop representing files or folders, and if I click on a folder it opened in Dolphin. A few days ago, it suddenly started opening Gwenview to see the folders - whether I inadvertently changed a setting, or this was done by a system update, I know not.

I've followed the advice in how-to-set-up-dolphin-as-default-file-manager, but it doesn't help; so I've uninstalled Gwenview. Ideally, I'd like Gwenview back as an image viewer, but Dolphin as default file manager. Is this possible, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the regular method to change your default applications is to go into

*System Settings > Default Applications*

and click on File Manager. You should see Dolphin as an option.

Click *Apply* when done.

I don't know whether this is the method you used, but let us know how you get on. I also see Gwenview as an option to be a file manager, which seems a little odd.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at _File Associations_ and one or two other options _in System Settings_ but these did not help.

Comment: Many thanks,@Drac Noc. I had looked at _File Associations_ and one or two other options _in System Settings_ but these did not help. I had also tried uninstalling Gwenview but it reasserted itself as default on re-installation. This time, after re-installation, I went to _Default Apps_, changed the default from Dolphin to Gwenview and back again, and it seems to have got the message.

Comment: Oh, well done! Good to see you got things working again.

Comment: For others - when I first opened the File Manager section of the Default Applications, it seemed that Dolphin was the selected default. However, my system was still using GwenView from Sublime and Firefox. I had to first change the default option away from Dolphin and apply the change, before reasserting Dolphin as the default and applying it one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to install `exo-utils` and it should provide `exo-preferred-applications`.

Run that in a terminal and under the Utilities tab, you should find the File Manager section. Specify Dolphin in that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 21.10 when using `gnome-disks` there is a bug (or not useful feature): clicking by "Mounted at link" under partition leads to open the folder in `Gwenview`, not in `Dolphin`.
To fix need to update `File Associations` in Settings:

- Known Types -> inode -> directory
- Remove `Gwenview`. `Kate` also is not needed here.